# S3 Bucket Policy TLS 1.2+

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tls1.2

I was hoping someone could confirm whether my current bucket policy is configured as expected to enforce TLS 1.2 and above.  As far as I can see it is configured correctly, but I keep getting emails from Amazon warning that as of December 31 2023 TLS 1.0 / TLS 1.1 will be turned off and connections to my S3 Bucket will fail.

Below is my current policy JSON:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[INSTANCE_NAME]-s3-live/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NumericLessThanEquals": {
                    "s3:TlsVersion": "1.2"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have used some online tools which do confirm that my bucket does support TLS 1.2+ but these emails from Amazon persist.

Below is a snippet of the email detailing the failure.

```
Please see the following for S3 buckets in which object-level calls were made over TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1 connections between July 17, 2023 and July 25,
2023 (the UserAgent may be truncated due to a limit in the number of characters that can be displayed):

Connections details will be in the following format:
Region | Bucket name(s) | APIAction | TLSVersion | NumCalls | UserAgent
eu-west-1 | [INSTANCE_NAME]-s3-live | REST.GET.OBJECT | TLSv1 | 5 |
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your policy `Allow`s requests (with an incorrect condition), but it does not `Deny` requests.

See https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/s3-enforce-modern-tls for the right policy:

```
{  
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AddPem",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::[INSTANCE_NAME]-s3-live", "arn:aws:s3:::[INSTANCE_NAME]-s3-live/*"]
      "Condition": {
        "NumericLessThan": {
          "s3:TlsVersion": 1.2
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The key difference is the `Deny` and `NumericLessThan`.

Comment: Thanks for that. At the moment I don't want to deny any requests. So it looks as though I am getting these emails because I am not denying them, but the above policy does in fact cater for TLS 1.2+

Comment: You get that email because you requests that still use old TLS versions and those will be automatically denied in the near future when AWS enforces this setting instead of you. This is basically a last warning to you to figure out which requests those are and fix them while you still have time. If you add this policy you can wait and see who comes and complains because something broke, then you can tell them how to fix it ASAP and in the meantime remove the policy again. That last step will not be an option when AWS enforces this setting.